# Can't save changes to system settings in Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, settings

I installed Debian Wheezy just a few days ago. I used the Live image, downloaded from official Debian website, to install it.

Now, the problem is that the changes I make to system settings (like changing keyboard shortcuts, wallpaper, etc), never apply. There are no "apply" buttons, so you'd expect it to work it soon after the change has been made. I've tried rebooting and it hasn't helped, unfortunately.

It's confusing because everything else seems to work fine (was able to install the wifi driver and such).

Any help will be highly appreciated. I can provide more details if a need arises.

---

### Edit - more details

How I make changes to the system settings:

1. I open the `System settings`,
2. Go to `Mouse & Touchpad`,
3. check/uncheck a checkbox or make any change,
4. close the window (there's no apply/OK button),
5. follow step 1 and 2 and the changes made are back to defaults.

I've been using Ubuntu previously (since 2011) and nothing of this sort ever happened. It appears the installation is buggy or something. :|

Comment: Can you be more specific how you are making the system setting changes?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thanks for the response. I've added the details.